# Долгая компиляция Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, mac

Ситуация такая, я обновился до новой системы **macOS Big Sur** - после этого компиляция каждого проекта занимает около **40** секунд, даже если нету ни одной строки. До момента обновления была такая же проблема, но только когда компилировал **первый раз**, все остальные сборки проекты были почти мгновенно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить проблему.

**Код пишу на C++**

Comment: Перейти на Windows / VS.

Comment: Проверьте что у вас стоит File - Workspace settings - Build System - New Build System

Comment: То есть до обновления пустые проекты в первый раз компилировало тоже 40 секунд и было норм?

Comment: @dIm0n ну, 1 компиляцию подождать это не так страшно

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk New Build System (default) стоит :(

Comment: А версия Xcode какая?

Comment: @VAndrJ 11.5 
А на Xcode 12 обновить не даёт :(